# Use jQuery.post() result in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got no clue how to do the following, so I wasn't sure what to search for either.

For validating my registration form I've a javascript function that checkes the existence of the inserted username in the database onblur of the username textfield.

```
function checkUsername(username){
$.post("checkmail.php", {username: username} , function(data){
var $response=$(data);
var response = $response.filter('#username-response').text();
if(response == "taken") {
    document.getElementById('username').style.borderColor = rood;
    valid = false;
}
});
```

}

This works fine, but now I want to validate it again onsubmit of the form in case users decide to submit an existing username.

```
function validateForm() {
    var valid = true;
    //checks different fields
    //now check voor username existence
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    checkUsername.call(username);

    if (!valid) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar enough with Javascript to get this working. Probably thinking in the wrong direction...

Comment: Just an interface thought. You could have a button that says Check Availability so that the onsubmit is not such a long query. Are you using server side tech at all?

Comment: Well if i understood it right, you will need to do synchronous ajax call for this as you are using return data for validation.

Comment: Yes, I'm double checking the input with php. My availability check is executed onblur the username textfield, this has the same effect as what you suggest with a button I guess. But just want to check again onsubmit...

Comment: @Ruchit Rami Thanks, the synchronous ajax call worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use synchronous ajax call for this as you are using return data for validation.